# How to update orders of records in SQL table using ajax in C# ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to change `OrderNumber` using JQUery sortable and Ajax. But formData is empty at all.

I'm using FormData to collect sorted rows and pass to API controller. Each time rows getting resorted, Ajax will call and so on, but the problem is before it the FormData is empty (console log report).

`AnswerSteps` table in database:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
[AnswerFA] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[AnswerEN] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[ImageURL] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[OrderNumber] [int] NOT NULL
```

View model:

```
public class SortedAnswersViewModel
{
    public List<string> SortedAnswerIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Jquery:

```
    var $sortableList = $("#sortable");
    var sortEventHandler = function (event, ui) {

        var data = new FormData();
        var $listElements = $sortableList.children();
        var listValues = [];

        $.each($listElements, function (i, v) {
            listValues.push(v.id);
        });

        data.append("SortedAnswerIDs", listValues);

        console.log(data); // data is always null here

        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
          //Some Codes
        });
    };

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            sortEventHandler();
        },
    });
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: That `data` is null doesn't make sense. Do you mean that `data` doesn't any of the listValues?

Comment: @rene sorry I mean it is empty without any element.

Comment: Add a `console.log($listElements)` and inspect if that collection does have items. Add a `console.log(v);` before `listValues.push(v.id);` to see if `v` does have an id property

Comment: @rene listElements and listValues have elements as well shown by console.log, for listValues after each sorting it returns correct sort. 0: "2" 1: "4" 2: "3" 3: "11"

Comment: Can you before your Ajax request do `data.forEach((v,k)=> {console.log(v,k);});` and check if that has output. In [my testing it does](https://jsfiddle.net/xmc0zy8a/).

Comment: @rene, console.log(v,k) works here. it returns all <li> elements. Very weird! Right after $.each loop and before ajax I putted codes to append listValues into FormData, but it returns empty!

Comment: So your code works. The `FormData`  class doesn't have a proper toString(), or at least it doesn't have a toString() that shows its content. That is why `console.log(data)` doesn't show anything useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194285/discussion-between-mehdi-and-rene).

Answer (score 0):

Try change this: var $sortableList = $("#sortable");

To this: var $sortableList = $("#sortable").val();